# Where can the using directive be placed in ASP.NET Razor pages?

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor, doctype

I've traditionally always put `@using` directives in my ASP.NET Razor pages at the top, along with the `@model` directive.  However, for my overall layout, I want to make sure the `DOCTYPE` declaration is at the very beginning of the document, so I want to push the `@using` down a bit.  Would you following be valid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    @using My.Library;
    <head>
        <title>Test web page</title>
        ...
```

Also, is there any documentation on where the `@using` directive can be used in Razor pages?  I can't seem to find any.  Is it valid to use it after some other Razor code, for example, or does it have to appear first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is valid and you can use `@using` any where before that you need that library.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx):

> HTML markup lines can be included at any part of the code.

so you can put `DOCTYPE` at the top of page.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that confirms this?

Comment: OK so I think the rule is that the `@using` directive needs to come before any other Razor code on the page, but doesn't need to actually be before non-Razor regular HTML markup.

Answer (score 7):

Up to .Net 4.5...

There is a `web.config` file in the *Views* folder, you can add `namespaces` in there, that is global to all views:

e.g:

```
<namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Globalization" />
        <add namespace="My.Library" />
</namespaces>
```

Comment: Unless you are using .Net 5 and MVC where there is no more web.config, instead try using the _ViewImports.cshtml, syntax example: 
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures